# Error al crear Procedimiento desde CLR

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net, stored-procedure

Estoy intentando crear un codigo CLR en una base de datos SQL Server 2012,
para ello he fusilado un sencillo codigo que no hace nada pero que deberia funcionar, ( es para ver que es lo que no funciona), porque me da el mismo problema que con el codigo real.

El codigo de la clase .net para el clr es el siguiente:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;

namespace CLRDemo
{
public class CLRFunctions
{

    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]        
    public static void Split()
    {
        //One line of C# code splits our string on one or more delimiters...
        //A string array is one of many objects that are returnable from
        //a SQL CLR function - as it implements the required IEnumerable interface.
        int a = 12;            
    }        

}
```

}

y luego la implantacion en la base de datos se ejecuta asi:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY CLRDemo
FROM 'C:\Pruebas\CLRDemo.dll'
WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_MySQLCLR
AS
EXTERNAL NAME CLRDemo.CLRFunctions.Split
GO
```

y el error que me da es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La verdad es que no entiendo porque no lo encuentra, si alguien me puede dar una pista se lo agradeceria,
Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías intentar distintas opciones:

```
EXTERNAL NAME CLRFunctions.Split
```

Ó bien:

```
EXTERNAL NAME Split
```